# How to combine the year, month, date , hour present in different column into yyyy:mm:dd HH:MM:SS format

Tags: python-3.x

year month day hour total_consumption 
Data is given in the above format in the csv and I need to convert it into YY/MM/D format and extract the particular month data. I tried to do datetime method of the pandas and was getting an error while parsing. I am new to the python, any solution to the above problem would be appreciated. Thanks.

df = pd.read_csv('./data2018/energy_clean.csv')
df['year''month''day''hour'']=pd.to_datetime(df['year''month''day''hour'], format='%y/%m/%d %H')

Comment: In java M=month, m=minutes, S=milliseconds: `yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: I have to implement in python

Comment: (I just wanted to warn, should you get mixed up numbers. I am not programming in python at the moment.)

Comment: is there a column with name `year''month''day''hour` in your csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are dozens of open [bugs](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20to_datetime) with the to_datetime api of Pandas. It works for raw data and converts to specified time format and not the dataFrame input. Please see my example for raw data below

```
pd.to_datetime(logs[0]['datetimestamp'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
Output:
datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 1, 0, 19, 40, 200000)
```

Here `logs` is a dictionary which I have passed to datetime function.

As a workaround, you can specify the date format while reading from the csv file itself. Use the below line to your code and let me know if this works

```
 df = pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=["year''month''day''hour"],date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%y/%m/%d%H"));
```